# Is Italian the only modern language that uses the feminine 3rd person singular pronoun for formal speech?

Tags: list-of-languages, pronouns, gender, italian, register

Is Italian the only modern language that uses the feminine 3<sup>rd</sup> person singular pronoun (*Lei*) for formal speech, regardless of the gender of the 2<sup>nd</sup> person singular addressee?

cf. [T–V_distinction#Italian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E2%80%93V_distinction#Italian)

Comment: German uses Sie for 3fs, 3cp, and formal 2cs.

Comment: Plenty of forms of address based on abstract nouns like *your highness* are feminine singular in European languages (eg Spanish *su Alteza*), they are just a bit too formal for everyday modern use between commoners.  T-V is an oversimplification, *Lei* is not really for *V*, *voi* is also used.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer In Italian *Voi* is extremely formal, to the point that I have seen it used today only in bureaucratic contexts or contracts. *Lei* is the standard respectful forms in Italian. *Voi* is not really used anymore.

Comment: @LukeSawczak. "sie" (she) and "Sie" (you, polite) are not the same word. The former takes a verb in the 3rd pers. singular, the latter a verb in the 3rd pers. plural.

Comment: @fdb Technically agreed — but if we slice it another way (the pronoun is the same, the conjugation is different) I think it can at least be submitted as relevant evidence :)

Comment: @Denis Nardin. True, we can safely say that in Italy _Voi_ has been today completely replaced by _Lei_. But I remember that in the 60s _Voi_ was still used by my grandparents when addressing any of their parents, as _Tu_ was considered too disrespectful at that time - I'm talking of pre-'68 here. And let's not forget that outside Italy, _Voi_ is still used in lieu of _Lei_ in the Italian-speaking cantons of Switzerland, or at least in the Southern part of the Ticino canton where I heard it being used.